# Visual Studio JSON Multiline String

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have a very simple json file

```
{
   "property" : "value"
}
```

The value in my application is quite long and Visual Studio forces me to write on a single line.  If I try to line break like this for my mere human eyes:

```
{
    "property" : "value value value 
                 value value"
}
```

I get an error as the string is not continued on the second line. I cannot seem to use the + operator either.

Does anyone have a suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: Are you reading this json file or creating ?

Comment: Creating. It is just that the JSON file has a neat structure which could be written easily across multiple lines on a single screen without scrolling.  When we are forced to write everything on a single line, it is almost unreadable.

Answer (score 4):

In Visual Studio, separating a string literal onto two lines as an end-of-line character to the end of the first line. Since "control" characters must be escaped in JSON, simply add a "\" to escape the EOL and JavaScript will ignore that character. For example:

```
{
   "property": "This is some text I want broken \(hit enter)
    into two lines"
}
```

should work fine.

Comment: That's I wanted :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding @ before multi-line string:

```
{
    "property" : @"value value value 
                 value value"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Shoaib. It appears to break the formatting though.